# Workflow "Wait for Field Change" trigger action if field is selected a second time

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

This 2013 list workflow works fine to assign to someone, send an email and complete the workflow when the status field is Completed.

My issue is if it is assigned back to someone before it is completed the email will not trigger if it has already been assigned to that person. Like it goes to Tiffany, then to Janet, and back to Tiffany. Tiffany won't get the email it has been assigned back to her.
I realize this how it should work but I can't figure out a way to get an email sent if it is reassigned back to someone that it was already assigned to.
[image]

Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since they are running in sequence the workflow will not "go back" to a previous step.  You will need to use if / else statements, or you can add a field to the list, call it "step", and trigger the emails on that - if step = 1 email Tiffany, if step = 2 email etc...... then have the workflow update the "step" column when the person has completed their task, or if it needs to go backwards then update the "step" column to go back to the step that you want.